# ScrollView wont scroll, xcode 4.2.1

Tags: xcode, user-interface, view, scroll

I am using the Interface Builder storyboard in xcode 4.2.1

I have already made a new .h and .m file for the scrollview.

I heard people talking about setting contentSize to something, but I don't know how to do that. Can someone help?

What I want is a simple scrollview which I can insert text and images into. And it has to scroll.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to set content size for scroll view in which your image or other view can scroll. It will be the total size of all view. You can set content size as followings:

```
[scrollView setContentSize: CGSizeMake(scrollView.bounds.size.width * numberOfPages, scrollView.bounds.size.height)] ;
```

Comment: ok, i got that. But now i can't seem to connect the class to the scrollview. I have made an IBOutlet in the .h, but I can't drag it onto the scrollview.

Comment: you need to add every view as subview to scrollview. as example: [scrollView addSubView:imgView];